# SaveChangesOnDbContextAsync has never been called

Tags: asp.net-core, abp

ABP has added an overridable function called `SaveChangesOnDbContextAsync` that allow us to intercept any insert/update/delete operation as in this link: https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/4659

I tried to override SaveChangesOnDbContextAsync in a class that inherits AbpDbContext like the following but it has never been called whenever I update the data:

```
public override async Task<int> SaveChangesOnDbContextAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
   {
       var result = await base.SaveChangesAsync();
       return result;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method is provided for your application code to bypass the logic in `AbpDbContext.SaveChangesAsync()`. ABP does not call it.

This is what the requestor meant:

```cs
public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    try
    {
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
    }
    catch (AbpDbConcurrencyException)
    {
        // Handle it
        // ...

        // Directly call Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext's SaveChangesAsync(bool, CancellationToken) to not repeatedly
        // create audit logs, update concurrencystamps, or trigger entity events etc. as AbpDbContext's version would do
        return await base.SaveChangesOnDbContextAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

You probably just want to override `SaveChangesAsync` instead.